# WAMP server redirect old domain names to new domain name?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, wampserver

I have WAMP server where there are 5 projects hosted 192.168.0.10 as

```
192.168.0.10:80
192.168.0.10:81
192.168.0.10:82
192.168.0.10:83
192.168.0.10:84
```

now I have changed and moved all these projects to new server 192.168.0.11 as

```
192.168.0.11:80
192.168.0.11:81
192.168.0.11:82
192.168.0.11:83
192.168.0.11:84
```

I want if someone still access
`192.168.0.10:80/*` it should be redirected to `192.168.0.11:80/*`

what will be best solution?
for time being I can keep old server and place there some file e.g. `.htaccess` for redirection

I tried below in `.htaccess` file at old server but still it is not redirecting

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine on 
   RewriteRule ^$ app/webroot/ [L]
   RewriteRule (.*) app/webroot/$1 [L]

   #code below is for redirtect
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^192.168.0.10$
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://192.168.0.11$1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: It might be better to create a virtual host for each site, then you would access them by name rather than by ip and all on port 80

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With your shown samples, could you please try following. Please make sure to place these rules always at top of your htaccess file. Values and etc are totally based on shown samples by original poster here.

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^192\.168\.0\.10:81$
RewriteRule ^ http://192.168.0.11:%{SERVER_PORT}%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,R=301,L]
```

***NOTE:*** As per OP's suggestion, edited line with port 81 here in condition line.

Comment: at second line I added port also`:81` also then it worked, if you see it will be ok, please update the answer for other users

Comment: @alamnaryab, sure, I would like to request you to update this one, since you are better person to update this one :) I will approve your edit too, cheers.

Comment: @alamnaryab, ahhhh sorry I am not sure about that error, ok please ping me your changed line here and I will edit it no issues cheers :)

Comment: second line= RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^192\.168\.0\.10:81$